# Random without parameters

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, functions

During a programming contest, I used the following line of code:

```
symbols[i] = random() & 0b11;
```

After the contest, when I looked into the Arduino reference, I found out random takes one or two parameters. Based upon that, I would expect the code not to compile. However, this code somehow worked as I expected. (Assigning a random number from 0 to 3) How come?

Answer (score 1):

Simple: `random()` isn't an Arduino function - it's a standard C function.

> **Function random()**
>
> `long random(void)`
>
> The `random()` function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the range of 0 to `RANDOM_MAX` (as defined by the header file `<stdlib.h>`).
>
> The `srandom()` function sets its argument seed as the seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers to be returned by `rand()`. These sequences are repeatable by calling `srandom()` with the same seed value.
>
> If no seed value is provided, the functions are automatically seeded with a value of 1.
>
> -- [AVR LIBC Manual Page](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdlib_1ga114aeb1751119382aaf3340355b22cfd.html)

Comment: The Arduino functions themselves, actually use the `random` function without arguments. [See source code](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp#L35-L50)